# How is a native executable built using Android NDK different from that built for Rasberry Pi using gcc-arm for Raspbian (pi-tools)

Tags: linux, gcc, android-ndk, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I recently built a simple Hello World program using NDK and tried it to run on my Rasberry Pi2 running Rasberry Linux distribution on a Arm processor. But, the OS could not recognize the executable and complained it not to be a valid executable.

I am wondering why this is the case? Why do we have a different build tool chain for Android and Raspberry even though both are Linux and ARM.

Answer (score 2):

Android uses armeabi or armeabi-v7a. On the other hand, Raspberry uses an incompatible gnueabihf ABI. Note that Android has Bionic runtime library, which is not exactly compatible with rest of Linux.